# Condição onde si for encontrado o nome "teste" imprimi OK se nao imprimir NO

Tags: awk

este e o código que estou querendo resolver e seu resultado!

`awk '{if ($0 ~ "teste") { print "ok"} else {print "no" }}' arquivo.txt`

```
no
ok
no
no
no
```

como pode ver ele verificou cada linha si tinha o nome ***teste***
e imprimiu ***ok*** e nas linhas que nao tinha imprimiu ***no*** !!

sei que o awk trabalha linha por linha!

queria q ele apenas me dissesse ***OK*** si tiver a expressão q eu busco ou ***NO*** caso nao exista!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Em awk:

```
awk '/teste/ {visto=1; exit} END {print visto ? "OK" : "NO"}' arquivo.txt
```

Explicação:

- `/teste/ { cosas }` quando Awk encontra o texto "teste", executa o código em `{}`.
- `visto=1; exit}` nesse caso, define uma variável booleana `visto`.
- `END {print visto ? "OK" : "NO"}` quando termina, mira se a variável es 1 o no. Si ela é 1, imprime "OK"; de outra forma, imprime "NO".

Mai eu prefiro Bash:

```
if grep -q "teste" arquivo.txt; then
   echo "OK"
else
   echo "NO"
fi
```

Em una línea:

```
if grep -q teste archivo.txt; then echo "OK"; else echo "NO"; fi
```

Comment: muito obrigado mano! era isso mesmo que queria! com bash eu sabia fazer mais queria so com awk!  mais pod me explica como funciona não intendi algumas partes!

Comment: @socketplus claro!  Atualizada

Comment: muito obg! @fedorqui